# Working of mbstocws

Tags: c++, linux

What are the default values does this mbstocws take?Will it behave similar to that of MultiByteToWideChar when we use CP_ACP,MB_PRECOMPOSED?

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup descriptions of Linux APIs using `man` command or internet search.

In your case [`man mbstowcs`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mbstowcs.3.html).